# Problem encountered with meson build. Need to specify real include path

Tags: cross-compiling, meson-build

I am trying to cross compile for glib 2.6 using meson. When i tried to build the glib, I have run into problems

```
[1093/1219] /opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++ -Itests/cxx-test.p -Itests -I../tests -Igmodule -I../gmodule -I. -I.. -Iglib -I../glib -Igio -I../gio -Igobject -I../gobject -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -g -pthread -MD -MQ tests/cxx-test.p/cxx-test.cpp.o -MF tests/cxx-test.p/cxx-test.cpp.o.d -o tests/cxx-test.p/cxx-test.cpp.o -c ../tests/cxx-test.cpp
FAILED: tests/cxx-test.p/cxx-test.cpp.o 
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++ -Itests/cxx-test.p -Itests -I../tests -Igmodule -I../gmodule -I. -I.. -Iglib -I../glib -Igio -I../gio -Igobject -I../gobject -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -g -pthread -MD -MQ tests/cxx-test.p/cxx-test.cpp.o -MF tests/cxx-test.p/cxx-test.cpp.o.d -o tests/cxx-test.p/cxx-test.cpp.o -c ../tests/cxx-test.cpp
In file included from /opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                 from /opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from glib/glibconfig.h:11,
                 from ../glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from ../glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from ../glib/glib.h:30,
                 from ../tests/cxx-test.cpp:1:
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:194:61: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
 #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                             ^
In file included from ../glib/galloca.h:32:0,
                 from ../glib/glib.h:30,
                 from ../tests/cxx-test.cpp:1:
../glib/gtypes.h:35:10: fatal error: time.h: No such file or directory
 #include <time.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

From the error message, I speculate that my include path in c-args might be wrong. Instead of `/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h`, I should be setting it to `/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/`

I have tried to change my cross file

```
[built-in options]
c_args=['--sysroot=/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux', '-I/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include', '-march=armv8.2-a','-O3','-ftest-coverage', '-fprofile-arcs','-Wall','-fmessage-length=0', '-fprofile-arcs', '-ftest-coverage', '-fPIC', '-pthread']
c_link_args = ['--sysroot=/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux','-L/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/lib','-lpthread', '-lgcov']
```

But the same error occurs. How do I solve it?

Thanks

===============================================================

Updates:

(1)
I tried to follow the steps in https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/Unable-to-cross-compile-gstreamer-application/m-p/1205304#M167111. still the problem exists

(2) Have tried to find time.h in my sysroot and tried to include in ... but the problem still exist

Snippet of my meson cross file. What am I missing?

```
[built-in options]
c_args=['-I/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include', '-I/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/src/debug/glibc/2.27-r0/git/time', '-I/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0','-I/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst', '--sysroot=/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux',  '-march=armv8.2-a','-O3','-ftest-coverage', '-fprofile-arcs','-Wall','-fmessage-length=0', '-fprofile-arcs', '-ftest-coverage', '-fPIC', '-pthread']
```

c_link_args = [ '-L/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/user/lib', '-L/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0', '-L/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/lib','--sysroot=/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux','-lpthread', '-lgcov']

Comment: have you found an answer?

Comment: @kochy: Nope I really couldnt find the answer to this problem...but the compilation of glib was kinda of trying to solve for another problem.... i have found the solution to other problem